# show not committed files in a specific directory (exclude others) in git

Tags: git, shell

I've directory structure like this:

```
RootDir
   `-----Code
   |       `-----Tests
   `-----Utils
   `-----Temp
```

I just mentioned the folders. I want to see any not-staged/not-committed file on `Code/` but not `Code/Tests/`

I want something like `git diff --name-only "ThisPath But Exclude ThatPath` but I couldn't find relevant exclude option in the `man git diff`. The content of files are not important for me and I just want to track any changes on a specific branch.

One possible solution might be GITIGNORE the desired path in the run-time (not in my .gitignore file). However I couldn't find such capability as well.

---

*p.s. my primary goal is to write a shell function which shows me whether there is a change in the specific directory branch relevant to the latest commit or not.*

*p.s. Using shell it's possible to pipe `git -diff --name-only` to some tools such as grep/ag/rg/etc, but I want  to try git based solutions first*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in bash, you can enable `extglob` and use exclusion pattern:

```
shopt -s extglob  #Enables extglob
git diff --name-only -- Code/!(Tests)
```

Comment: I'm using zsh and `git diff --name-only -- Code/^Bench*` works as you said. But I'm using Matlab `system()` function to execute git command hence globing isn't available.